# Group argument in aesthetic when working with percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a problem of Data visualization from "R for Data Science."

Problem 5. In our proportion bar chart, we need to set group = 1. Why? In other words what is the problem with these two graphs?

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop..))

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = ..prop..))
```

As you see the codes and the results of them, there is a problem in y-axix because of not including group argument. I'm clear with that, so after changing the orginal codes into the below.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., group = 1))

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = ..prop.., group = 1))

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = ..prop.., group = color))
```

I could deal with the first one, which is colored by black. But the Problem is the next one. I know that including "group = 1" will be just like the black bars so changed "group = 1" into "group = color". The y-axix is prop now, but it's not exactly what I want because the sum of whole proportions of all levels in cut variable(x-axis) have to be 1 (=100%) but it exceeded 1. I want to change the value of proportion (y-axis).

I would appreciate if you help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `..prop..`calculates the percentage within group. It needs a grouping-variable otherwise each `x` is its own group and `prop` = 1 that is 100%, for every `x`.

When you put `group = 1` `prop` is the percentage of x of all entries, since all entries belong to the same group. You found that out already.

In your last plot, when you group by `color`, the percentages are calculated within the colours. That means every color sums up to 1.

Is this what you try to achieve?

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = color, y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering thr question! Is there another way to draw a graph of proportion as the y-axis keeping the shape of bar chart? I mean each bar of cut variables should not be 100%, and the sum of each proportion is 1.0(100%)

Comment: I figured it out now, I changed the code you wrote, especially deleting position so that the bar is stacked now. I appreciate your answer!